# How to ensure a certain key value pair in Typescript Object remains at the last position

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, key-value

I need to create a Typescript Object in which a certain element with the key 'NONE' always remains at last. I need this to ensure that while rendering this object in my HTML page its value appears at bottom.
So basically I need an implementation of myObject.shiftKeyToLastPosition(keyname);

I've tried deleting and re-appending and reduce method. That didn't help.

Comment: There is no way to do this. In Javascript, objects are unordered lists. To have items in a specific order you must use an Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your properties are string, you could try this

```js
const source = {
  'Domestic': '1',
  'NONE': '0',
  'Wild': '2',
};

const { NONE, ...dest } = source;
dest.NONE = source.NONE;

console.log(dest);
```

Here we are creating a new object without the `NONE` key and then adding `NONE` key at the last.

As per ECMAScript 2015 spec, the traversal of an object with string keys would yield keys in order of insertion.

P.S: Assuming that you have only integer and string keys, no Symbol keys.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [proxima-b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205011/how-to-ensure-a-certain-key-value-pair-in-typescript-object-remains-at-the-last#comment113534529_64205011), there's no way to deterministically order an object.

What you can do though, is create an helper function that lets you define the order in which you'd like to display the key/values. The cool thing with Typescript is that you can do that in a type safe way!

```
const myObject = {
  'hello3': 'Value 3',
  'hello1': 'Value 1',
  'hello2': 'Value 2',
  'hello4': 'Value 4',
} as const;

function orderObjectToArrayKeyValue<Obj>(obj: Obj, orderKeys: { [key in keyof Obj]: number }): { key: keyof Obj, value: Obj[keyof Obj] }[] {
  return Object
    .entries<number>(orderKeys)
    .sort(([, order1], [, order2]) => order1 < order2 ? -1 : 1)
    .map(([key]) => ({ key, value: obj[key as keyof Obj] }) as { key: keyof Obj, value: Obj[keyof Obj] });
}
```

With the above example, if you call:

```
console.log(orderObjectToArrayKeyValue(myObject, {
  hello1: 1,
  hello2: 2,
  hello3: 3,
  hello4: 4,
}));
```

You'll get

```
[
  {
    "key": "hello1",
    "value": "Value 1"
  },
  {
    "key": "hello2",
    "value": "Value 2"
  },
  {
    "key": "hello3",
    "value": "Value 3"
  },
  {
    "key": "hello4",
    "value": "Value 4"
  }
]
```

Then using the framework of your choice, it'll be really easy to loop over that array and display the values (+ use the key if needed).

Here's a [live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDDAOQAWGANlSAMykBcZAagIZUCuGMDANMTKUaIAIxNWHbjHECSFarQBME0uy48VcoYpAAWVeukGBAXxhsIMUJCgBuQoQBmnMNgCW4GCABOAEwwfVExsABUQAEEfHzYEAGkMBCMMAB5ggD4AChB0ZmC%20b39AhIQIZnwYAG0Aa0SYdzAYWoQQJxhggF1mME44FECYUwBKcqbE5mbW9vQCgDcpDDz0GsSpzsHKjoJBHwwoTh9G4KwoQRIAOgwwKB93DAgUnr7ArN8AnxKIIbOYc4hfKCZTKVApvQKiDoFEGFd5KDpDGA4dIw8EwFIonxKGAAfhgAFpRDBmKJviQLnA2AAHIErBDwxHIzIVZpzBbMHJoWkWKyTNrrYbcghjBATVZ8mYweYaJac3nTNBbYYOUyOGz-KgYc60ADm2SKQXQJ3CURi8USyUyiGO2AKRBIwloomJ2gdICUzCULt0dGYdC9Ij0zD0ZiGQzsQA) *(press enter while focusing the left side and it'll run the code, the output will be displayed in your console).*